# About the difference that saving card information to "card object" "source object"

Tags: stripe-payments

When registering a card (assuming later reuse) I think that there are cases when creating and saving card object and saving by creating and saving the source object. What is the difference between them?
Please tell me about "merit" and "disadvantage"

As described below "Use of this API is no longer recommended", is the way to create the source object old?
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/cards

Also, do you need to create a PaymentIntent object in order to save to the "card" on the dashboard?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers

Comment: PaymentIntents are the Stripe solution to the upcoming SCA changes in Europe in September. If your company is based in or does business in the EU you should look into it.